# xml serving/reading error at System.Xml.XmlDownloadManager.GetNonFileStream IIS related?

Tags: .net, xml, iis-7, xslt-1.0

I have an aspx page, that serves xml that is loaded in an xslt like this:

```
   <xsl:variable name="newsurl">http://mytesturl.dk/public/simpeldatalist.aspx?method=getnews</xsl:variable>
   <xsl:variable name="news" select="msxsl:node-set(document($newsurl, /))"/>
```

, which worked fine on my development server.

Moving to live server, this does not work any more, but throws up like this:

```
 System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error. at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() at
System.Xml.XmlDownloadManager.GetNonFileStream(Uri uri, ICredentials credentials) 
at System.Xml.XmlDownloadManager.GetStream(Uri uri, ICredentials credentials) 
at System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri, String role, Type ofObjectToReturn) 
at System.Xml.Xsl.Runtime.XmlQueryContext.GetDataSource(String uriRelative, String uriBase) 
--- End of inner exception stack trace --- 
at System.Xml.Xsl.Runtime.XmlQueryContext.GetDataSource(String uriRelative, String uriBase) 
at (XmlQueryRuntime {urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt-debug}runtime, XPathNavigator {urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt-debug}current) 
at (XmlQueryRuntime {urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt-debug}runtime, XPathNavigator ) 
at Root(XmlQueryRuntime {urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt-debug}runtime) at Execute(XmlQueryRuntime {urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt-debug}runtime) 
at System.Xml.Xsl.XmlILCommand.Execute(Object defaultDocument, XmlResolver dataSources, XsltArgumentList argumentList, XmlSequenceWriter results) 
at System.Xml.Xsl.XmlILCommand.Execute(Object defaultDocument, XmlResolver dataSources, XsltArgumentList argumentList, XmlWriter writer, Boolean closeWriter) at System.Xml.Xsl.XmlILCommand.Execute(IXPathNavigable contextDocument, XmlResolver dataSources, XsltArgumentList argumentList, XmlWriter results) at System.Xml.Xsl.XmlILCommand.Execute(IXPathNavigable contextDocument, XmlResolver dataSources, XsltArgumentList argumentList, Stream results) at System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform.Transform(IXPathNavigable input, XsltArgumentList arguments, Stream results) 
at Dynamicweb.Base.XmlXsltParse(XmlDocument xmlDoc, XslCompiledTransform transformer, TextWriter tw, XsltArgumentList xmlargs)
```

Both the live and development server shows the same xml when calling the page in browser(empty at the moment):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<newsitems>
</newsitems>
```

Changing the url in the xml on live to read from test server works.... so: Live and dev server can read from dev, but none can read from live...

Apparently the live server has some setting, that does not allow the calling of the page in that manor.

can anybody think of a reason for this? Some security setting? I don't know exactly what more info to provide, so please ask if you find you are missing som information...

Feeds:

Will not load in xslt: http://www.osterbo.dk/public/simpeldatalist.aspx?method=rawxml&dbsqlforxml=getnews

Will load: http://osterbo.bleaudev.dk/public/simpeldatalist.aspx?method=rawxml&dbsqlforxml=getnews

regards,

Steen

Comment: The problem is partly solved.... I have found that using this a approch: http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/xslt/8360-Consuming-and-RSS-Feed-and-the-500-Error fixes the problem. How ever, I don't like using C# in xslts when it is not normally needed. So I still want to figure out why that server demands the headers to be sent along...

Comment: Steen, I get both documents using MSXML3 and MSXML4. I guess this would also be the case with MSXML6, but I need to set some command-line parameter to allow the execution of the `document()` function. Hope this information may be useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:variable name="newsurl">http://mytesturl.dk/public/simpeldatalist.aspx?method=getnews</xsl:variable>
```

Should be

```
<xsl:variable name="newsurl">http://mytesturl.dk/public/simpeldatalist.aspx?method=rawxml&amp;dbsqlforxml=getnews</xsl:variable>
```

You didn't define your query parameters correctly, also remember in XML to escape ampersands to & a m p ;

---

The only other difference is 
http://osterbo.bleaudev.dk/public/simpeldatalist.aspx?method=rawxml&dbsqlforxml=getnews
Contains this header
**X-Robots-Tag  noindex,nofollow,noarchive**
While http://www.osterbo.dk/public/simpeldatalist.aspx?method=rawxml&dbsqlforxml=getnews
does not